# If $A = -A^{T}$ (where $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$) then $\forall t \in \mathbb{R},$ prove that $\det (I+tA^2) \geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A = -A^{T}$ (where $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$) then $\forall t \in \mathbb{R},$  prove that $\det (I+tA^2) \geq 0.$

My attempt: Let the eigenvalues of $AA^{T}$ be $\lambda_{i}$ (for $i =1, \ldots n$) then we know $\lambda_i \geq 0$

$\det(I +tA^2)= \det(I -tAA^T) = \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-t \lambda_i)$ 
 the roots of which occur at $t= \lambda_{i}^{-1}$ for those $\lambda_i$ which are non-zero. But why should $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-t \lambda_i) \geq 0$ *for all* $t$? What if $n$ were odd and all the $\lambda_i$'s were distinct and greater than $1$? Then the above expression at $t=1$ would be less than $0.$ Any thoughts on how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The matrix $A$ is *skew-symmetric* and its nonzero eigenvalues are all purely imaginary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u$ be a unit eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$, then we have $\lambda=\langle Au, u\rangle=-\langle A^Tu,u\rangle =-\langle u, Au\rangle=-\overline{\langle Au, u\rangle}=-\bar{\lambda}$, i.e. $\lambda$ is purely imaginary or $0$.

If the canonical form of $A$ contains a Jordan block with dimension more than $2$, then there exist (orthonormal) $u,v$ such that $Au=\lambda u$ and $A v=\lambda v+u$, then $\langle Au, v\rangle=\langle\lambda u, v\rangle=0$, but
$$\langle u, A^Tv\rangle =\langle u, -Av\rangle=-1$$
which is a contradiction. Therefore, $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues purely imaginary or $0$.

Note $A$ is a real matrix, thus if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $\bar{\lambda}=-\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue.

Let the non-zero eigenvalues of $A$ be $\pm\lambda_i\sqrt{-1},1\le i\le N$, then
$$\det(I+tA^2)=\prod_{i=1}^N (1-t|\lambda_i|^2)^2\ge 0.$$